# ¿Cómo hago para que un arreglo pase a otra variable de manera aleatoria?

Tags: javascript

> var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//Quiero pasar el arreglo a una variable pero de forma aleaotoria

> var aleatoria = [3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 4];

Comment: Edgar Bienvenido. Que haz intentado?, que haz probado hasta el momento ?, lo haz intentado, si es así te recomiendo que lo pongas acá y nos aclares cual es el problema que tienes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías usar el método `sort` que se encarga de reordenar el `array`, y con la función definimos el modo de ordenamiento que va a tener dicho `array`, gracias al `Math.random()` podemos ordenarlo de manera aleatoria:

```js
var lista = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5];
var aleatorios = lista.sort(function() {return Math.random() - 0.5});

console.log(aleatorios);
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. :)

Comment: @EdgarMartínez te invito a que consideres marcar la respuesta como aceptada para cerrar la pregunta, también te invito a que te hagas el [tour] y entiendas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio, además ganarás tu primer medalla, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haria de esta forma:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5];
var length = array.length;
var result = [];

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  result.push(array[index]);
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(result);
```